# Need help Converting a jQuery event to a Drupal Behavior

Tags: javascript

I have a Drupal 7 web site that is using jQuery animations to fadeIn div tags.  I need an event to capture a fadeIn when it is completed.  I have found a sample jQuery example that does what I need it to, but I have not been able to successfully convert it to a Drupal 7 behavior and I'm not quite sure what I might be missing.

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/tkoscielski/dpz4rrxb/1/)

Below is my Drupal JS file, `fadeInEvent.js`.

```
Drupal.behaviors.fadeInEvent= {
    attach: function (context, settings) {

        var _old = jQuery.fn.fadeIn;

        jQuery.fn.fadeIn = function() {
            var self = this;
            _old.apply(this.arguments).promise().done(function(){
                self.trigger('fadeIn');
            });
        };

        jQuery('.tab-pane').bind('fadeIn', function() {
             alert('fadeIn Done.');
        });

    }
};
```

In the above JS code, I never get my alert that the fadeIn has finished on the item I have selected.

Comment: My advice would be to take the monkey patching out of the behavior altogether (it doesn't belong there). You might just see it start to work after that

Answer (score 1):

Alter don't show because in your code:

```
jQuery('.tab-pane').bind('fadeIn', function() {
             alert('fadeIn Done.');
        });
```

this function mean that when selecter **.tab-pane** fadeIn done, alert will show. But You don't call fadeIn => don't have event fadeIn. You need call that same:

```
jQuery('.tab-pane').fadeIn(2000);
```

And better function **jQuery.fn.fadeIn** need outside Drupal.behaviors.fadeInEvent

```
(function ($) {
    var _old = $.fn.fadeIn;
    $.fn.fadeIn = function(){
        var self = this;
        _old.apply(this,arguments).promise().done(function(){
            self.trigger("fadeIn");
        });
    };

    Drupal.behaviors.fadeInEvent= {
        attach: function (context, settings) {

            $('.tab-pane').bind('fadeIn', function() {
                alert('fadeIn Done.');
            });
            $('.tab-pane').hide();
            $('.tab-pane').fadeIn(2000);
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

then you call fadeIn() every where and have event fadeIn.